# php pdo where ? не работает

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Вот код html:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search_text">
    <input type="text" name="search_by">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="OK">
</form>
```

В поле search_text вводится текст для поиска в БД

В поле search_by вводится название столбца, в котором искать текст

Вот, код, который обрабатывает эту форму:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$_GET["search_by"], "%".$_GET["search_text"]."%"]);
```

Пользователь вводит все данные верно, но этот код не работает? Никаких ошибок нет, но в результате выдает ноль строк.

Если убрать $_GET["search_by"] (WHERE ?), и вместо него написать так: WHERE login (т.е. принудительно подставить нужное поле):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute(["%".$_GET["search_text"]."%"]);
```

То все работает. Вопрос: почему первый вариант кода не рабоатет?